# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] SSL support is not available in this build

Tags: php, soap, https, openssl

I am trying to send a secure soap message and I get this error:
*SoapFault exception: [HTTP] SSL support is not available in this build*

I can do https requests to my server without a problem. Also I have made sure that:

1. extension=php_openssl.dll is present and uncommented in my php.ini
2. LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so is present and uncommented in my httpd.conf

When I look at my phpinfo SSL is showing as enabled every where except in PHAR (I doubt it matters there, but correct me if I'm mistaken).

I am using XAMPP on Windows if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For Unix-

Add this line / uncomment this line.

```
extension=openssl.so
```

For Windows-

Add this line / uncomment this line.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```